# Java while loop with array

Tags: java

Suppose that p is a two-dimensional array with elements of type int. Which of the statements below best describes the effect of the following code?

```
int i = 0;

while ( i < p[ 0 ].length )
{
  p[ 0 ][ i ] = 0;
  i++;
}
```

Could someone translate this to plain english for me? 
I only understand that the loop will keep going when `i < p[0].length` but what is `p[0]` and what is `p[0][i]` ?

Comment: What resource did you referred to understand this thing, that couldn't explain it clearly?

Comment: My that sounds like ... you just copy and pasted your homework here.

Comment: That's exactly what this is. Unfortunately people will promptly do his homework for him...

Comment: Just one question from my side. Have you started your programming career directly with Java. I mean, if you have learnt `C`, then you should not have such doubts in any language.

Comment: I know all the element in the first row will be assign to 0. <<That the solutions. I'm just asking to explain what does p[0] and p[0][i] mean in plain english.

Comment: `p[0][i]` is the _ith_ element of the first array in an array of int arrays.

Comment: @ Rohit, yes I started directly with Java.

Comment: @Rennade.. In that case, I would just give you an advice. Learn `C` first. In Java, you have got a vast library and APIs that has solved most basic programming problems, which you may tend to use without having to do any efforts. Thus you will not learn the basics of programming, which is very important. In my opinion, `C` is the best language to start programming with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"i" equals zero
"p" is an array of arrays
while i is smaller than the "first" array's size in p
    give 0 as value to i'th element of first array in p 
    increase i by 1
```

Comment: +1 - if you're going to answer someone about their homework, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `p` is presumably an `int[][]` - an array of array of ints.

`p[0]` is the first element of `p`, and has type `int[]`. The `[]` operator indexes into the array. `a[n]` fetches the element at index n from the array `a`. Note that it uses 0-based indexing so the first element has index 0 (not 1 as you might have expected).

The loop sets all elements in `p[0]` to the value `0`.

Note that this can also be done more concisely using [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29). The following code has the same effect as the loop you posted:

```
Arrays.fill(p[0], 0);
```

Comment: This is clearly a question pasted directly from a homework assignment, so he's probably not interested in alternate approaches. He just wants his homework done for him.

Comment: Maybe he is not, but other people reading this might be. This site is for everyone.

Comment: That's true, but a question like this is pretty specific to the OP. It's not exactly the kind of question that other people will stumble across. But... I guess it's possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Mark. I'll be sure to keep this in mind when I learn Array next.

Answer (score 0):

It's a loop that increments `i` for the length of the 1st array of the `p` array, setting the `i`th element to `0`.

In java `p[0][i]` is the same as `p[i]` for the 1st array of `p`.

Presumably, `p` is declared as `int[][] p`

Comment: Your second statement is highly problematic.

Comment: @RohitJain youre right - i realised that before seeing your comment actually - I correct it

Comment: No, you didn't. I know what you're getting at, but the way you're trying to say it isn't right / is confusing. How about "`p[0][i]` gives you the element at index `i` in the array stored at `p[0]`"

Answer (score 0):

p[0].length refers to the size of the second specified dimension as in if have an array with n dimensions say int a[][][][][][][][...n times then a.length refers to first dimension, a[0].length will refer to the length of second dimension etc.

p[0][i] obviously refers to the first row with column index specified by i's current value.